# DB2 SQL - Get specific row_number values in sub queries

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, row-number

I'm creating a DB2 SQL query that subqueries to get the SUM(CHARGE_AMOUNT) from another table.  This works fine.

Now I need to break out the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd CHARGE_AMOUNT fields so I can see:
DETAIL_LINE_ID, TOTAL XTRA CHARGES, XTRA CHARGE 1, XTRA CHARGE 2, XTRA CHARGE 3

I'm unable to get this to work, seemingly because TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID is not in scope in my sub-sub-query.

[SQL error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdHAR.png)

SQL below...  Please advise if there's a better way to perform this query.

```
SELECT "TLORDER"."DETAIL_LINE_ID",
"TLORDER"."BILL_TO_NAME", 
"TLORDER"."TOTAL_CHARGES", 

-- THIS WORKS: Get the sum of the 3 extra charges from table: ACHARGE_TLORDER 
(SELECT SUM(CHARGE_AMOUNT)
FROM TMWIN.ACHARGE_TLORDER 
WHERE ACODE_ID NOT LIKE 'FSC%' AND DETAIL_LINE_ID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID) "TOTAL XTRA CHARGES",

-- NOT WORKING: Get the most recent extra charge
(SELECT CHARGE_AMOUNT "XTRA CHARGE 1" FROM
(
SELECT CHARGE_AMOUNT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DETAIL_LINE_ID ORDER BY ACT_ID DESC) AS rn 
FROM TMWIN.ACHARGE_TLORDER WHERE ACODE_ID <> '' AND ACODE_ID NOT LIKE 'FSC%' 
AND DETAIL_LINE_ID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID
) 
WHERE rn = 1),

-- NOT WORKING: Get the 2nd most recent extra charge
(SELECT CHARGE_AMOUNT "XTRA CHARGE 2" FROM
(
SELECT CHARGE_AMOUNT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DETAIL_LINE_ID ORDER BY ACT_ID DESC) AS rn 
FROM TMWIN.ACHARGE_TLORDER WHERE ACODE_ID <> '' AND ACODE_ID NOT LIKE 'FSC%' 
AND DETAIL_LINE_ID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID
) 
WHERE rn = 2),

-- NOT WORKING: Get the 3rd most recent extra charge
(SELECT CHARGE_AMOUNT "XTRA CHARGE 3" FROM
(
SELECT CHARGE_AMOUNT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DETAIL_LINE_ID ORDER BY ACT_ID DESC) AS rn 
FROM TMWIN.ACHARGE_TLORDER WHERE ACODE_ID <> '' AND ACODE_ID NOT LIKE 'FSC%' 
AND DETAIL_LINE_ID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID
) 
WHERE rn = 3)

FROM   "TMWIN"."TLORDER" "TLORDER"
WHERE  "TLORDER"."BILL_TO_CODE"!='' 
AND ("TLORDER"."PICK_UP_BY_END">='9-12-2021')
```

Here's a simplified data sample:
[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ1Pt.png)

Comment: Your query looks excessively complex for the task it's doing. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Seems like it possible to do it in a simpler way.

Comment: What is the field name in the TLORDER table -- it is not DETAIL_LINE_ID -- is there a field named that or does the DETAIL_LINE_ID only exist in the charge table -- maybe you need to link the charge table to the order table based on the order id?

Comment: I added a sample data model image to the main post.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to join the order table and the line table -- but assuming there is a way you can do this query like this:

```
WITH LINE_WITH_ROW AS (
  SELECT
     ORDER_ID, 
     CHARGE_AMOUNT, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DETAIL_LINE_ID ORDER BY ACT_ID DESC) AS rn 
  FROM TMWIN.ACHARGE_TLORDER 
  WHERE ACODE_ID <> '' AND ACODE_ID NOT LIKE 'FSC%' 
)
SELECT
  TLORDER.ORDER_ID, 
  --TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID, -- can't work not in the table.
  TLORDER.BILL_TO_NAME, 
  TLORDER.TOTAL_CHARGES, 
  R1.CHARGE_AMOUNT as CHARGE1,
  R2.CHARGE_AMOUNT as CHARGE2,
  R3.CHARGE_AMOUNT as CHARGE3
FROM   TMWIN.TLORDER TLORDER
LEFT JOIN LINE_WITH_ROW AS R1 ON TLORDER.ORDER_ID = R1.ORDER_ID AND RN =1
LEFT JOIN LINE_WITH_ROW AS R2 ON TLORDER.ORDER_ID = R2.ORDER_ID AND RN =2
LEFT JOIN LINE_WITH_ROW AS R3 ON TLORDER.ORDER_ID = R3.ORDER_ID AND RN =3
WHERE  TLORDER.BILL_TO_CODE!='' AND (TLORDER.PICK_UP_BY_END>='9-12-2021')
```